# How to load Properties from Eclipse Program Argument

Tags: java, eclipse, properties

The following program successfully prints 4 properties as expected

```
public class TestingStringProps {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String s = "name=file\npath=/var/log/mine/\nhost=localhost:9092\nport=9999";
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(new StringReader(s));
        System.out.println("Number of Props: " + props.stringPropertyNames().size());
        for (final String name : props.stringPropertyNames()) {
            System.out.println(props.getProperty(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if i pass the same string as Program Argument in eclipse, it considers the whole String as one property.

How to pass a string of properties in eclipse?

Requirement: I have simplified the question here. In our project a program gets a string of properties like the above from another program and it is working fine. I wanted to test the second program independently.

Comment: `Number of Props: 4
/var/log/mine/
9999
file
localhost:9092
` - works fine for me.

Comment: If you debug your application what does the string look like in the Eclipse case? How are you passing those properties from Eclipse, i.e. what does the argument look like? Normally, when passing properties from the command line you'd use something like `-Dname=file -Dpath=...`. If you need to support a single string then you'd probably use something like `-Dprops="name=file\npath=...`

Comment: @Thomas, I am passing it as Program Argument and reading it as as args[0]. In Program Argument, I am passing it as "name=file\npath=/var/log/mine/\nhost=localhost:9092\nport=9999"

Comment: What does `args[0]` look like when you debug your application? What's the difference to the value of `s` in your question?

Comment: @Thomas, I tried printing the args[0] in the actual application. It shows a commented line at the top and each property in a new line.

Comment: @Thomas, I found the solution. Instead of \n character, i pressed enter key and made sure that each property is in a new line. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the code a bit. Then need to set the program arguments as below (need to add space in between each property)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  String str = String.join("\n", args);
  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.load(new StringReader(str));
  System.out.println("Number of Props: " + props.stringPropertyNames().size());
  for (final String name : props.stringPropertyNames()) {
     System.out.println(props.getProperty(name));
  }
}
```

program argument: `name=file path=/var/log/mine host=localhost:9092 port=9999`

Comment: I do not have the control on the program who is sending the argument. I will get the properties as one long String. 
I tried to simplify the question by writing a simple program.

Comment: @Mac you can split by new line and modify your code to process it line by line.

Comment: I found the solution. Instead of \n character, I place each property in new line (by pressing enter key). Now i am able to test the second program independently.